# C Lynda.com tutorial files not compiling in terminal or Eclipse

Tags: c, terminal, eclipse-neon

Lynda.com
Course: C Essential Training

**Issue 1**: Project File - 00_04.c 
- Terminal: compiles and runs OK. 
- Eclipse Neon: Builds but doesn't display output in console. (created with Toolchain: MacOS X GCC)
 

**00_04.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    puts("!!!Hello World!!!"); /* prints !!!Hello World!!! */
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Eclipse console output**

```
15:49:04 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project NewProject ****
make all 
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.

15:49:04 Build Finished (took 99ms)
```

**Issue 2**:  Project - 02_01.c
- Terminal: not recognizing included files

**02_01.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>          // Notice the library included in the header of this file
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "myLibrary.h"      // Notice that myLibrary.h uses different include syntax
```

**myLibrary.h**

```
#ifndef MYLIBRARY_H_
#define MYLIBRARY_H_

void function1(void);
void function2(void);

#endif /* MYLIBRARY_H_ */
```

**myLibrary.c**

```
void function1(void){
    puts("It works :)");
}

void function2(void){
    //This function does nothing as well
}
```

**Terminal Output**

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_function1", referenced from:
      _main in 02_01-7f91e4.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: What is the makefile you are using for the first example? And in the second one you have a linker error (also where is `function1` defined there??)

Comment: @UnholySheep sorry. copied in wrong code for myLibrary. Fixed in OP. That's where function1() is located.

Comment: That's only the declaration of the function. Where is its definition/implementation?

Comment: The definition of function1 is still not shown. What file is that located in? Is that file included in the compilation (likely not)?

Comment: @Evert in the myLibrary.h file the prototype for fuction1 is there. Good point though. It won't call if it isn't actually defined.  It's off though. This is the exercise file right from lynda.com.  And when the author runs the file, it works the first time.  He doesn't have the prototype defined either.

Comment: @Evert sorry. found it. added myLibrary.c to the end of OP.

Comment: What is the console command you are running to compile?

Comment: How are you compiling and linking things on the command line/terminal?

Comment: @SanchkeDellowar cc 02_01.c

Comment: @dbconfession See my new answer

Answer (score 1):

If you're running `cc 02_01.c` as the command. Then the compiler is trying to look for a `main()` function in file (02_01.c) or the included files (myLibrary.h).

There is no `main()` function in either 02_01.c nor myLibrary.h, so you get that compiler error.

To fix, make your 02_01.c look like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>          // Notice the library included in the header of this file
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "myLibrary.c"      // Notice that myLibrary.h uses different include syntax
int main(void)
{
    function1();
    return 0;
}
```